# Tipagem de um ponteiro para struct

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, tipagem, lista-encadeada

Me foi sugerido construir uma lista encadeada utilizando a seguinte `struct` como nó:

```
typedef struct node *link;

struct node{
    int item;
    link next;
};
```

Como eu não entendi o que significa o operador ponteiro junto com esse `typedef` pesquisei e acabei achando que nesse caso `link` passa a ser um apelido para ponteiros para a estrutura `node`. Sabendo disso comecei a criar a lista com base nessa ideia, mas logo no começo já encontrei erros, o código é compilado corretamente, mas a janela de execução trava logo em seguida.

Código que estou começando:

```
int main ()
{
    link l;

    l->next = NULL;
}
```

Suponho que eu esteja usando o "apelido" do ponteiro de node erroneamente. Qual a forma correta de usá-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você declarou a variável mas não atribuiu nenhum valor a ele. Aí tentou modificar o valor dela. Isto gera erro. Tem que inicializar a variável. Por se tratar de um ponteiro, a inicialização se dá por alocação de memória.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *link;

struct node {
    int item;
    link next;
};

int main(void) {
    link l = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    l->next = NULL;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/qRQryy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/idjxjnuz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Node.c).

Documentação da [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Tem muita coisa pra aprender para usá-la. Não é tão simples quanto parece.

Os compiladores podem gerar erro nesses casos com a devida configuração. Quando eu compilei seu código no ideone gerou erro. Isso poupa muito tempo tentando achar erros obscuros.